# KendoUI Image browser

Tags: kendo-ui

I have added the KendoUI Image Browser to my application but when it opens up, I get the browser (upload, select, delete, sort, search...etc) but do not get the "Insert or Cancel" buttons... Nor do I get the "Web address" and "tooltip" bit at the bottom.

I'd like to have the whole image browser (I don't want to use the editor).

Any help would be appreciated.

Instead of this:
[image]

I get this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div id="imgBrowser"></div>

$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#imgBrowser").kendoImageBrowser({

                //imageBrowser: {
                    messages: {
                        dropFilesHere: "Drop files here"
                    },
                    transport: {
                        read: "/ImageBrowser/Read",
                        destroy: {
                            url: "/ImageBrowser/Destroy",
                            type: "POST"
                        },
                        create: {
                            url: "/ImageBrowser/Create",
                            type: "POST"
                        },
                        thumbnailUrl: "/ImageBrowser/Thumbnail",
                        uploadUrl: "/ImageBrowser/Upload",
                        imageUrl: "/ImageBrowser/Image?path={0}"
                    },
                    change: function () {
                        //this.value(); //Selected image URL
                        console.log(this.value());
                    }
               // }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears the ImageBrowser can *technically* be used outside of the Editor, but it is not officially supported. Here is a thread on the Telerik forum concerning this issue:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/why-not-make-image-browser-in-editor-as-separate-controle

Here are the most notable quotes:

> You can initialize an image browser widget from a regular  element. The configuration is the same as when using the image browser inside an Editor.
>
> http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/editor#imagebrowser-object

```
<div id="imgBrowser"></div>

$("#imgBrowser").kendoImageBrowser({
    transport: {
        read: "/service/ImageBrowser/Read",
        destroy: {
            url: "/service/ImageBrowser/Destroy",
            type: "POST"
        },
        create: {
            url: "/service/ImageBrowser/Create",
            type: "POST"
        },
        thumbnailUrl: "/service/ImageBrowser/Thumbnail",
        uploadUrl: "/service/ImageBrowser/Upload",
        imageUrl: "/service/ImageBrowser/Image?path={0}"
    }
});
```

> The ImageBrowser exposes three events
>
> - change - when a file is clicked
> - apply - when a file is double-clicked
> - error - when a request fails
>
> The change and apply events do not expose the clicked file, but you can find it out by checking which .k-tile element has a k-state-selected class.
>
> The ImageBrowser does not expose an event related to folder navigation. You can get or set the current location with the widget's path() method.

Answer (score 1):

> The change and apply events do not expose the clicked file, but you can find it out by checking which .k-tile element has a k-state-selected class.

It's possible to get current selected item with something like this without checking for k-state-selected class:

```
        change: function(е) {
            var selectedImage = e.sender._selectedItem();
            console.log('selectedImage', selectedImage);
        }
```

I haven't checked it for apply event.